# Testing haskell functions that return errors

Tags: haskell, testing

Hi I have a similar to the following haskell function

```
test :: Int -> Bool
test 1  = error "shouldnt have been 1"
test 2  = error "shouldnt have been 2"
test 11 = error "shouldnt have been 11"
test 77 = error "shouldnt have been 77"
test _  = True
```

I have a testing scheme to test bad inputs to make sure they return the correct error

```
tc1 = test 1
tc2 = test 2
tc3 = test 11
tc4 = test 77

allTests = [tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4]
```

But the problem is that when I run `allTests` in ghci, I only get the first error. I would like to have a list of all the errors

How can this be done or some way I can catch the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use `catch` from `Control.Exception`, but that's still an awkward way to achieve the goal.

It'd be better to use a pure data type to capture errors, as they're easier to compose and collect. Normally, you'd use `Either` for that, but in this particular case, the success case would carry no information, so the type would be `Either String ()`, which is isomorphic to `Maybe String`. Rewriting `test` to return `Maybe String` is trivial:

```
test :: Int -> Maybe String
test 1  = Just "shouldnt have been 1"
test 2  = Just "shouldnt have been 2"
test 11 = Just "shouldnt have been 11"
test 77 = Just "shouldnt have been 77"
test _  = Nothing

tc1 = test 1
tc2 = test 2
tc3 = test 11
tc4 = test 77
tc5 = test 5
```

I added a `tc5` value in order to demonstrate what happens when a test succeeds.

You can evaluate all of those test cases, but if you want only the failure cases, you can use `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
allTests = catMaybes [tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5]
```

Here's the result of running `allTests`:

```
*Q46376632> allTests
["shouldnt have been 1",
 "shouldnt have been 2",
 "shouldnt have been 11",
 "shouldnt have been 77"]
```

---

If you can't change the function you're testing, you can try something like the following, but it's hardly elegant:

```
tc1 = catch (print $ test 1) (\err -> print (err :: SomeException))
tc2 = catch (print $ test 2) (\err -> print (err :: SomeException))
tc3 = catch (print $ test 11) (\err -> print (err :: SomeException))
tc4 = catch (print $ test 77) (\err -> print (err :: SomeException))
tc5 = catch (print $ test 5) (\err -> print (err :: SomeException))

allTests = sequence_ [tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5]
```

When running it, you get output like this:

```
*Q46376632> allTests
shouldnt have been 1
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at 46376632.hs:14:10 in main:Q46376632
shouldnt have been 2
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at 46376632.hs:15:10 in main:Q46376632
shouldnt have been 11
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at 46376632.hs:16:11 in main:Q46376632
shouldnt have been 77
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at 46376632.hs:17:11 in main:Q46376632
True
```

At this point, you'd probably be better of using a proper testing framework.

Comment: Hi thanks. I like the code block with `tc1 = catch (print $ test 1) (\err -> print (err :: SomeException))` `...`

Comment: I have a question, if I have a list ie `allTests = [tc1,tc2,tc3,tc4]` can i use something similar on this list in order to reduce the duplicate code ??

Comment: @Jhoy First, understand that that `catch` code is not elegant, or even appropriate, Haskell code. That said, you can use `map` (or `fmap`) on `[a]`.